# Drawing a double line border to the cell in itext Table

Tags: java, itext

I am using itext for creating the content in PDF.

I want to draw a double line border to the bottom of the cell in PdfPTable.

I tried using two cells, for one cell giving the border to TOP and for the other giving the border to BOTTOM.

But of no use.

Can anybody help me in this issue asap ...

Answer (score 0):

You should turn the border off like this: `setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);` and then use cell events or a table event to add your custom borders. See for instance the [`DottedLineCell`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/DottedLineCell) example. You'll need to adapt the code that draws the dotted lines by code that draws double lines.